# How to filter based on a property of an inner object in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
    const collection = [
      {
        inner_obj: {
          prop: "A"
        }
      }
    ]

    collection.find(
      //code to find outer records based on the `prop` property of column `inner_obj`
    )
```

how to find outer records based on the `prop` property of column `inner_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items in the array which don't match the condition:

```js
const desiredProp = "A"

const collection = [{
  inner_obj: {
    prop: "A"
  }
},
{
  inner_obj: {
    prop: "B"
  }
}]

const filtered = collection.filter(e => e.inner_obj.prop == desiredProp)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
collection.find({"inner_obj.prop": "A"})
```

Comment: that does not work

Comment: I thought I was referring to how to filter a nested object in mongo.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field

Comment: The find statement would come immediately after a `populate` statement. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I'm not sure. But in the documentation I see that it should be first find statement and then populate statement, or in any case filter it in the same populate statement. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions